# jQuery file upload doesn't submit extra parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I need to use the formData parameter available in the jQuery File Upload control to send additional data to the server on submit.  The default implementation for formData is to invoke a function that grabs all controls in the form and serializes them to an array (using the jQuery serializeArray() method).

I have controls in my form, but when the file is uploaded, I am not getting any additional data.  When I inspect via Fiddler, there is nothing in the request that shows these form fields are being submitted.

Is there something additional that needs to be done to get these to submit?

Btw, these two links discuss formData...

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options
...for this one search the page for formData.

For what its worth, the `multipart` option is set to true.

Comment: Can you provide your current code? otherwise we have no idea if you are using the plugin incorrectly etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also needed to pass an extra parameter and here is what i used :

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {
                    param1: 'test'
                    ,param2: "value2"
                    ,param3: "yasseshaikh"
              }
});
```

The [formData option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data) can be used to set additional form data programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Complete code (I modified the answer provided by Yasser)

Add these code into  jquery.fileupload.js

```
submit: function (e, data) {

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
          formData: {
                 param1: 'test'
                ,param2: "value2"
                ,param3: "yasseshaikh"
          }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If the blueimp plugin isn't a requirement I would really recommend the jquery malsup form.

You can use a regular multipart form and just create a regular file input field along with other input fields of your own choice and everything is submitted as usual.

Reference: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Code sample:

```
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind Your data to fileupload.  Look at this question
[Blueimp jQuery file upload, passing extra form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459236/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-passing-extra-form-data)