# How to retrieve form data posted with jQuery fileupload to Java servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, servlet-3.0

The jQuery fileupload docs say that I can send additional form data parameters by setting the `formData` parameter to an object before submitting it. I'm doing that like this:

```
data.formData = {'a':'one', 'b':'two'};
```

...and then calling `data.submit()`. My Java servlet (3.x) gets called, but when I try to retrieve the parameters in the normal way e.g.

```
request.getParameter("a");
```

...there's nothing there (i.e. it's `null`). I've looked in `request.getParameterNames()` and `request.getParameterMap()` too, they're both empty.

How can I access the parameters?

These are my fileupload initialization options:

```
url: '/my-upload-servlet',
autoUpload: false,
singleFileUploads: false,
maxFileSize: 9000000,
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|tif|tiff|pdf)$/i,
dataType: 'json',
previewMaxWidth: 128,
previewMaxHeight: 85,
disableImageResize: false,
previewCrop: true,
```

I've also tried setting the `formData` option to an array of objects, which the docs say is also an option, e.g.

```
data.formData = [ {name:'a', value:'one'}, {name:'b', value:'two'} ]
```

...but it still doesn't work.

Here's the full code snippet for uploading the file (the commented out stuff are the other things that I've tried):

```
var params = new FormData();
params.append('params', JSON.stringify({a:'one', b:'two'}) );
data.formData = params;

//data.formData = {a:'one', b:'two'};

//data.formData = [
//    { name: 'a', value: 'one' },
//    { name: 'b', value: 'two' },
//];

//data.url = '/my-upload-servlet?a=one&b=two';

data.submit()
    .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Hurray!');

    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Boo!');

    }).complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        console.log('Done');
    });
```

None of these are working for me.
No matter which of the above methods I try, calling `HttpServletRequest.getParameter("a")` or `HttpServletRequest.getParameter("params")` (in the case of the FormData) always returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

We can't send an `object` in the payload of file upload (`multipar`) request. We can only send key value pairs. However, if we want to send a `json` then we first need to convert it into the string, using:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Once this is done, we can send it in the request payload and deserialize it in servlet e.g.:

```
mapper.readValue(request.getParameter(""), YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Fair enough, but the docs do say that you can specify an object and pull out the parameters in the usual way (search for 'formData'): https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Comment: You are correct. It says so, however, I came across similar issue a few days ago and managed to resolve it this way.

Comment: Once I've `stringified` the form data, how do I set it before sending? Is it `data.formData = JSON.stringify(formData)`? And what is the name of the parameter? (for the getParameter() call on the server side)

Comment: `var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', <file object>);
data.append('param_name', <stringified value>);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Why are you appending the file object to the FormData object. Is that not already taken care of?

Comment: Can you please add the full request payload in the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647503/jquery-file-upload-doesnt-submit-extra-parameters Can you have a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

I only realized after examining the Chrome developer console that the request has been including the parameters in the request payload all along (even when setting the `formData` to an object).

The problem has been accessing them at the servlet. This question put me on the right path: [Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

I'm actually using Apache Commons FileUpload at the servlet end, so I was able to access the parameters with something like this:

```
FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while ( iterator.hasNext() ){
    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
    String paramName = item.getFieldName();
    InputStream paramValueStream = item.openStream();
    // do it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me greatly, with sending a file using a `jQuery FileUpload` plugin to a Java Servlet:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32555960/2668852